# How to parse JSON to Dart list

Tags: json, dart, flutter

How do I parse a complex JSON into a list in Darts/flutter

I have the message in a map but I need some help parsing and getting the value

This is the JSON:..

```
 {
        "jobs": [
            {
                "id": "S_1244",
                "title": "Title1",
                "location": {
                    "city": "Miami",
                    "stateCode": "FL"

                },
                "salary": {
                    "symbol": "US$",
                    "min": "26.15",
                    "max": "27.15"
                },
                "type": "Temporary",
                "posted": 1530027914570

            },

             {
                "id": "S_1234",
                "title": "Title1",
                "location": {
                    "city": "Miami",
                    "stateCode": "FL"

                },
                "salary": {
                    "symbol": "US$",
                    "min": "26.15",
                    "max": "27.15"
                },
                "type": "Temporary",
                "posted": 1530027914570

            }
       ]
 }
```

I have the body in a map

Map map = jsonDecode(data.body);

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to model everything in your json. Here's the code for start.

```
  Map myMap = json.decode(response.body);
  Iterable i = myMap['jobs'];
  List<Jobs> jobs = i.map((model) => Jobs.fromJson(model)).toList();
}

class Jobs {
  Jobs({this.id, this.title, this.type});
  String id;
  String title;
  String type;

  Jobs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        title = json['title'],
        type = json['type'];
}
```

You will end up List of Jobs, which is plain old java class representation of your jobs in your json. You can model location and salary too.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner way to do this with mappings, but seems to work.

```
  Map map = jsonDecode(data.body);
  List jobList = map["jobs"];
  for ( var job in jobList ) {
    print("id= ${job['id']} title=${job['title']}   location=${job['location']['city']} ");
  }
```